# In Internet Explorer, a form submits when a submit button is clicked, but refuses to submit when called through JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a very simple form with a file field in it.
I have not overriden the Submit action in any way, nor is my submit button names "submit".
I am trying to submit the form programatically through JS.
This works great in FF and Chrome, but is failing in both IE 8 and 9.
The weird thig is that if I press the Submit button - it works like a charm.

I can't figure out what the problem is - any ideas what to look for?
I've been racking my brain on this for hours.

Comment: If you don't post the code it may be extremely hard for people to help.  Have you tried using the IE debugging tools to look for errors or otherwise diagnose the problem?

Comment: Can you share your html and the javascript you are trying to submit the form with?

Answer (score 0):

How do you submit the form programatically? Like this?

```
document.forms['formid'].submit();
```

What does the IE when you try to submit the form? Nothing happens?

Comment: I've tried every way I can think of:

            $('form').submit();
            document.getElementById('fileSubmitForm').submit();
            document.forms[0].submit();

And IE just ignores it - nothing happens.

Comment: Does this little test work for you? Clicking the submit link should blank the page cause the form gets submitted by the submitform-function. Calling this function programatically should deliver the same result.
http://jsfiddle.net/WHDxx/8/

Comment: Nope... it just isn't doing anything... this is so weird.

Comment: So it seems that there is a problem with your IE? I've tried this in IE 7, 8 and 9 without any problem.